# Matrix inverse $A^{-1}$ as linear combination of the powers of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, power-series, inverse, matrix-calculus

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be any invertible matrix. Can $A^{-1}$ always be expressed as a linear combination of the powers of $A$, i.e. $$A^{-1}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty c_iA^i\,,$$
for an appropriate choice of coefficients $\{c_i\}_{i=0}^\infty$?

Comment: Use Cayley-Hamilton. The matrix $A$ satisfies its characteristic polynomial, the constant term of which is non-zero because it is the determinant. If the characteristic polynomial is $a_nx^2+...+a_1x+a_0$. Then $A^{-1}=(-a_nA^{n-1}-a_{n-1}A^{n-2}-...-a_1)/a_0$

Comment: @pulosky Multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Solved! ;) Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Interesting side-note.  For a "typical" matrix $A$, any matrix that commutes with $A$ is a polynomial in $A$.

Comment: technically it should be $$ A^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}(A-I)^{n}$$

Comment: @JoseGarcia I think your expression (Neumann series) is only true if $||A-I||<1$. Instead I'm supposing $A$ is any matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use Cayley–Hamilton.

There is a nonzero polynomial $p$ such that $p(A)=0$ because $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ has finite dimension, and so $I, A, A^2, \dots, A^{n^2}$ cannot be linearly independent.

Let $m$ be a polynomial of least degree such that $m(A)=0$.

Write $m(A)=0$ as $Ap(A)=-m(0)$.

If $m(0)=0$, then multiplying both sides by $A^{-1}$ gives $p(A)=0$, which cannot happen because $\deg p < \deg m$.

Therefore, $m(0)\ne0$ and  $A^{-1}=-\frac{1}{m(0)}p(A)$.

Comment: @pulosky, see the details in my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Use Cayley Hamilton to find such an expression.